# Is it possible to split a value from a row into other rows according to a condition (seek string in list) and delete the row that had the value split

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe, numpy

I want to delete a row in a dataframe if a certain string isn't inside a list and then split the value of that row in the other rows.

But I'm struggling how to do this.

So for example:

```
# list for categories

print(list_cat)

['FREIGHT CHARGES', 'PETROL', 'ADDITIONAL STOP', 'OTHERS', 'TOLL', 'DANGEROUS GOODS']
```

```
test = df_pivot.query('LOAD_ID_VR == "19082022121669VR00158480"')

test.head()

LOAD_ID_VR  Status  Status_2    Claim Amount    Indicator   Value   categories
6   19082022121669VR00158480    To correct  pass    NaN Adjustment Freight Charges  -625.00 FREIGHT CHARGES
3200    19082022121669VR00158480    To correct   pass   NaN Ajustment Petrol Diff   -41.45  PETROL
6394    19082022121669VR00158480    To correct   pass   NaN Ajustment Manual Rate Diff  333.23  MANUAL RATE
```

I don't have `'MANUAL RATE'` in the list, therefore what I am trying to reach would be a solution that deletes the line with `'MANUAL RATE'` and splits the 333.23 inside the other 2 rows.

and get this as end result:

```
test = df_pivot.query('LOAD_ID_VR == "19082022121669VR00158480"')

test.head()

LOAD_ID_VR  Status  Status_2    Claim Amount    Indicator   Value   categories
6   19082022121669VR00158480    To correct  pass    NaN Adjustment Freight Charges  -458.335    FREIGHT CHARGES
3200    19082022121669VR00158480    To correct   pass   NaN Ajustment Petrol Diff    125.215    PETROL
```

The solution should be automatized for other keys and categories since this is a big dataframe. Is it possible to do this?

Answer (score 1):

I'd first add all "non-distributables", then evaluate on how many "distributables" this can be distributed and then do the rest (you can definitely do this with less code -- I just wanted to make it as comprehensible as possible):

```
import pandas as pd

list_classes_remove = ["M"]
df = pd.DataFrame(
    data={
        "CATEGORY": ["F", "P", "M", "F", "P", "P", "M"],
        "ID": ["1", "1", "1", "2", "2", "3", "3"],
        "VALUE": [-625, -41.45, 333.23, 50, 100, -40, 10],
    }
)

df_distribute = (
    df.loc[lambda x: x["CATEGORY"].isin(list_classes_remove)]
    .loc[:, ["ID", "VALUE"]]
    .groupby("ID")
    .sum()
    .reset_index(drop=False)
    .rename(columns={"VALUE": "VALUE_DISTRIBUTE"})
)

df_no_distributables = df.loc[lambda x: ~(x["CATEGORY"].isin(list_classes_remove))]
df_factor = (
    df_no_distributables.loc[:, ["ID", "VALUE"]]
    .groupby("ID")
    .count()
    .reset_index(drop=False)
    .rename(columns={"VALUE": "COUNT"})
)

df_no_distributables = df_no_distributables.merge(
    right=df_distribute, left_on="ID", right_on="ID"
).merge(right=df_factor, left_on="ID", right_on="ID")
df_no_distributables["VALUE"] = df_no_distributables.apply(
    lambda x: x["VALUE"] + x["VALUE_DISTRIBUTE"] / x["COUNT"]
    if x["COUNT"]
    else x["VALUE"],
    axis=1,
)
```

Comment: I was able to do something that follows what I intended due to your explanation! @abbasador

Comment: Awesome, happy to hear!